# Cannot open the datafile in a SSIS process

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I have a simple SSIS pipeline that gets data from a .csv file on a local computer and inputs it into a database on a remote SQL server. I have prepared a package in Visual Studio which works on execution and have deployed it to a Integration Service Catalog. When I attempt to manually execute the package in SSMS Catalog or on a schedule through SQL Server Agent, I am getting the following error:

> Data Flow Task: Error: Cannot open the datafile "C:\Users\user\folder\data.csv"

I have verified that:

1.The package author corresponds to the account executing the package

2.The  SQL server user has Full control and Modify permissions for the `\folder` and the .csv file

Most solutions online point to these two points, however I am still getting the same error

Comment: And SSIS is running on the local computer?

Comment: It is running on the remote server

Comment: And why do you expect it to open a file on the C: drive of the local computer?  The remote server has its own C: drive.

Comment: You need to use the UNC path here. Though I would also suggest that the file not be in a user's user folder; as it's actually unlikely that the SQL Server service account does have access to it. It should be in a specific directory that is being shared on the network.